# How to get a pointer to point to its grandparent

Tags: c++, pointers, object, graph, this

I have a tertiary tree/ graph, and one of its children needs its child to point back to its parent.

```
class TTree
{
public:
    tTree();
    ~tTree();

    TTree *back;
    TTree *forward;
    TTree *left;
    TTree *right;

    int numsteps;
    bool ifVisited = false;
    bool ifExpended = false;

    void insert(int steps, TTree *direction);
}
```

In the insert `*back` has to point back to itself.

```
TTree::insert(int steps, TTree *direction){
    this->direction = TTree();
    this->direction->numsteps = steps;
    this->direction->back = this;
    this->direction->forward = NULL;
    this->direction->left = NULL;
    this->direction->right = NULL;
}
```

I came up with this, but I'm not sure if `this->direction->back = this` the right hand `this` would point to itself as the object calling the function, or instead it would refer to the left hand statement of `this->direction->back`

Comment: 'this' is the instance on which the method has been invoked. It has nothing to do with the lvalue you mention.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly the root nodes `back` pointer should be `NULL` signifying that it is the root and that it has no parents. When inserting a new node you would have to have the parent setting up the child and use the parents `this` as the value for the childs `back`.

```
//called within parent node
TTree::insert(int steps, TTree *direction){
    direction = new TTree();
    direction->numsteps = steps;
    direction->back = this;
    direction->forward = NULL;
    direction->left = NULL;
    direction->right = NULL;
}
```

You do not use `this` for the `direction` variable because it is not an member of the object `this` refers to, It is a pointer to the object within `this` which is not quite the same thing.

also I believe you would want to use dynamic memory on the line `direction = TTree();` because it looks like you are trying to assign a temporary object to a pointer which would not work. So rather use `direction = new TTree();`Just remember to call `delete` on it later so you do not leak the memory.

I hope this solves your problem. If not please let me know what I missed so I can give it another shot.

Good Luck